# Blender crashes when I render animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I recently got a new computer and since then every time I go to my computer and wake him up to see what frame the render is at, Blender just gives up and crashes, it happens to every blender file new or old, I am using an iMac. I don't know how to send the cash log

Comment: Hi. I see you have tagged this with the 'blender-render' tag. Does this mean you are using a version of blender prior to 2.8?

Comment: Render from your commandline, if it crashes it should give you the appropriate error message in the commandline.

Comment: Not a memory problem. It would give the "out of memory" error if so.

Comment: @RayMairlot ,WhatAMesh and Nate_Sycro27. i am using blender 2.8.2a, I don't know what you mean with command line and im definitely not out of memory its just wenn I use the compute while its rendering or when the Mac is turned on while rendering . Im getting an error message but its way to long to send so I don't quite understand how to send it